Meaning of the joke A: "how much coke do you do" B: "Yes."
I have seen several YouTube comments or memes, with the same pattern that a person asks a question for example starting by "how much", .... and the other person say "Yes" in the answer. I don't remember them vividly, but I saw one of them on YouTube yesterday:

A: "how much coke do you do"
B: "Yes."

I don't completely understand the joke. I think it is intended to say that the person is very addicted to cocaine (I realized it when I read the replied comments on YouTube).
However, I don't know where these patterns of jokes come from and why would answer "Yes" to a question started by "how much". Are there cultural references for them?

You understand the lan language used, you understand the (unfunny) joke. Your question is really about the Internet, and how people pick up on a trend and just go with it until it becomes either embarrassing or "untrendy". Do you remember all those "lolcat" jokes that imitated Yoda speech? They're still out there but that fire is largely burnt. With the one-word answer "Yes", the Internet hasn't reached that stage of saturation yet.

All this to say, as I see it, your question is off topic.

@Mari-LouA But is it really off topic? I heard this pattern offline, and sometimes it's not a joke, it's an obfuscation to avoid a straight answer.

I've explained why I don't consider it an English language problem. I understand the bewilderment of non-native speakers but this is, as you rightly pointed out, a cultural issue: sometimes referred to as  pop culture

This is similar to: What are you high on? I think culturally bound questions are on topic here.

I don't get the joke at all. I could see if A said: do you want one line of coke or two? Then yes would make sense. This sounds like the teller of the joke was high when he wrote the joke.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AllOfThem

See also: the equivalent question from English Language & Usage

@JohnDouma Interesting that "yes" sounds to you like a sensible answer to "one or two?", but not to "how much?"  To me, these seem equally nonsensical, and equally derailing if the asker is trying to ask a simple question.  I have always wondered why people think it's funny.  Yes, it sounds like the person saying "yes" is high, in either case, and yet otherwise intelligent non-high people seem to laugh.  I don't really get it.

@DonHatch The reason yes makes sense is because a statement like A or B is a logical disjunction which is true or false.

@JohnDouma That is true on one reading of “A or B” but is, of course, usually a wilful refusal to understand a common and useful usage. Up to an age between 10 and 15 one may take it is a sign of linguistic awareness. Beyond that it is in danger of becoming tiresome.

@PJTraill That's why it's a joke. The listener is interpreting a choice as a disjunction. When I was in middle school, I had a math teacher who used to ask students: do you walk to school or carry your lunch? It's the same thing. I didn't find it funny in middle school but I got the joke.

For the record, I would say the most comment variant of this is, “How many times have you watched this video/reel/thing? Yes.”

This is a pretty recent joke format, which I believe has only come into widespread use online in the past few years, so I think it's young enough that there isn't complete agreement on where it came from or exactly how to interpret its semantics. The other answers make some sense, and I have my own guess, but from an ELL point of view, I think the important thing is this:
This usage of "yes" is only used in this kind of joke format. Saying "yes" is not a standard way to answer questions of degree. It would not ever be used in normal conversation, unless one was trying to imitate this kind of joke.
That being said, as a native speaker, I don't find this kind of joke all that funny specifically because the grammar and semantics don't make sense. But I believe I understand what it's trying to get at -- in your example, the idea is that there is no amount of coke that Person B would be satisfied with, so the answer of "yes" suggests something like "all of it -- all the coke in the world."
Before this joke format came around, there was a similar kind of joke which made more sense (as Reinmar Bielau notes in their answer), where someone would answer "yes" to a question of "do you want X or Y?" For example, "Do you want cake or ice cream? Yes."
In that joke, the idea of the "yes" answer was that the person did not want to make a decision at all, and says "yes" as a way to try to choose both. I suspect that the new joke format came about from people copying that template without thinking too hard about it, and applying it to questions of degrees rather than ones where someone is asked to make a choice. From there the "yes" slightly expanded in meaning from "both" to "all" or "as much as possible."

I experienced this joke as early as the 1990s, so it's not from the last few years.

Also, the equivalent question from English Language & Usage, which @Slate linked to above in the comments replying to OP, mentions the Benny Hill Show.  (Which I am 90% sure is even older.)

(And which I now see that @Simon Baars actually mentioned first in their answer, though I imagine they could've known about it separately.)

Thank you (and @Reinman Bielau below) for bringing up "Do you want cake or ice cream? "Yes."  Distinct, but most likely related.  I think they're probably right that it's an outgrowth of that format.  One tiny ultra-pedantic quibble:  in that older joke format, I don't think it's that someone is indicating they don't want to make any choice, just that they don't want to have to choose between.  They are making a choice, quite enthusiastically: they choose "BOTH!" when the question implied "either".  ...I'm on the fence as to whether that's a real distinction here or not.

I'm not sure I agree that it comes from people "not thinking hard" about the template.  To me, the whole "joke" part of it is extending the template to the point that it's almost senseless.  Like the joke is that "yes" is both inappropriate, and implies "a lot".

Compare the related joke where a person, filling out a form with a blank for "sex" enters "yes".

As another way of viewing the response, it could be interpreted as suggesting there is no possible phrasing of the question which would result in a response of "no". In a way, the speaker is simultaneously answering "do you do a little coke/do you do a moderate amount of coke/do you do a lot of coke" all at once. The answer suggests there is no amount for which the answer is "no".

@MJD That joke is not related. In that scenario, there the field labeled "Sex" on a form where the intention was to ask about the person's biological sex/chosen gender, but the answerer is deliberately (or, perhaps more humorously, unintentionally) misinterpreting the question to be asking whether they have had/want to have sex and are answering "Yes".

Another explanation of the “Do you want A or B?” “Yes.” form is that the second person is answering the question in a pedantic, strictly logical way: they do want one of A or B.  (And if the questioner had wanted to know which, they should have asked that!)

@Bemisawa (and cbg), it isn't about not wanting to make a choice. The joke is based on the fact that "do you want A or B" is inherently ambiguous. It can mean "which of A or B do you want?" or it can mean "do you want at least one of A or B?". The classic example is answering "yes" to "is it a boy or a girl?", because the joker interprets the question as "does it belong in one of the two categories?" and not as "which of the two categories does it belong to?". As gidds says above, it's a classic grammar pedant's joke.

I see two possible explanations for the joke:

As Reinmar Bielau states, it's an evolution of the more easily understandable joke format:


A: Do you want X or Y?
B: Yes.

This is a play on the fact that there's no distinction in English between an inclusive "or" and exclusive "or", so B is free to interpret the question as not asking them to choose between one of the two, but whether they want at least one of the two, and give a funny non-answer that doesn't tell A what A wants to know - that is, which of the two does B want.
What makes this even funnier (or at least let's say so for the sake of argument) is that - since the "or" can be interpreted inclusive - answering this way lets B get away with requesting both things, probably to the dismay of A who was only offering a single alternative.
And if you can answer a question that makes you choose which thing you want with an answer that doesn't require you to make that choice and lets you have all of it, you can perhaps also extend that to quantitative questions like "how much":

A: How much X do you want?
B: Yes.


"Yes" is a very basic positively charged word. It's the simplest way to express something positive - an agreement, a want, in some contexts things like happiness, and so on. It's one of the first words someone learning English - or even a child learning to speak - would learn.

So someone answering "yes" in this context could be communicating "I want it so much/I want so much of it I can't even think straight enough to give you a proper answer, just revert to the most basic way of responding positively I know."

(as anyone knows, a joke thoroughly explained is twice as funny)

A real-life example of the "X or Y" variant is a tire advertisement from Dunlop, probably from the 1980s: "Is the Dunlop SP a safety- or a longlife-tire?" -- "Yes."

I don't really see how the last paragraph follows… at least, not in standard English.  It seems to be twisting the words out of their usual meanings.

"...there's no distinction in English between an inclusive 'or' and exclusive 'or'..." This is only true if you're a programmer, mathematician, or logician familiar with Boolean logic. Otherwise, in English, "or" is always exclusive. The joke of answering "yes" to this question is far more than that, anyway, because a more reasonable, predictable, grammatical answer that assumed "or" could be inclusive would simply be "Both." Which does get used in real-world discourse.

@CodyGray yeah, it's in the "technically correct" realm, but it's certainly inclusive in a lot of contexts - if you're told "you can bring your own snacks or drinks" to an event, they're likely not going to kick you out if you bring snacks and drinks.

(or "driving drunk or high is prohibited" - you're not allowed to be drunk and high, either).

My simplified view of the "how much" - "yes" pattern is that no matter how much the person who anwers has already consumed from something, if asked if they wanted more, they'd definitely answer "yes" - meaning "really a lot", and this is the way they want to describe how much really is that. It can be true and used as an obfuscation to avoid a straight answer, or an exaggeration as a joke.
My answer if of course not comprehensive, I don't know the cultural reference.

I have seen this joke type before, and I think it is simply about the second person being so mentally affected by a drug that they cannot answer the question appropriately. How much weed do you smoke? Yeah, man! Or something wildly unrelated. A variant of some 'crazy person' jokes.

@MichaelHarvey Yes, that's also a variant, but many times it is intentional from a sane person.

@MichaelHarvey: I've seen "how much" -> "yes" in contexts where deranged mind isn't a plausible answer. It's more like it means "all the things" or "all the ways" or some such.

I think examples of "how much/yes" are where they cut off the question: "should I go to the liquor store and..." "Yes!". A similar joke is letting them talk more and then saying "you had me at liquor store".

@OwenReynolds Good point to bring up, and related in some ways, but I don't think this is the same joke.  "How much coke do you do?" "Yes." still works when the first sentence is completed without being cut off.  "Yes" is, effectively, used here to specify an amount... it's a stand-in for a very, very large degree.  Someone described it as hyperbole, which I think is correct.  The jokes you mention are similar in that they express enthusiasm through hyperbole, but the internal logic is different.

I see it as outgrowth of "Do you want X or Y? Yes." meaning, you want both of them.

How does this answer the question? I don’t understand.

@user1176409: I do. I haven't made up my mind how good of an answer it is but it's definitely a plausible answer.

@Joshua I see this as partly an excellent answer and partly incomplete.  It is excellent, in that this is very plausibly an outgrowth of the older joke format, and that context of how this joke (may have) developed is quite relevant and possibly very useful.  But, it is incomplete, in that the meaning has shifted slightly between these two formats, and they don't really get into how it has shifted - it sounds a bit like they're implying that it means more or less the same thing.

Taking them a bit too literally, you wouldn't respond to "How many cars do you download?" "Both of them."  But, you might respond (cheekily!) with "All of them!" or "All the cars!" (as @Joshua mentioned), which I think was Reinmar's point.  That's hyperbole (so, a very similar ), but that said, it's subtly different than "Yes", because wanting to get all of the options is subtly different than (even more hyperbolically) having all of something.  I do think they're on the right path here, though.  I think this answer does advance the conversation.

This is a fairly probable etymology and, while short, I'd say it's the right answer - the joke evolving from a play on the inclusivity of "or" in English to something of a non-sequitur. You can still sort of get the joke without knowing this - "yes" is a positively charged word, and you can infer that in context it means "a lot/everything/everywhere, etc.", perhaps interpret this as "I want this so much that I'm not even thinking straight enough to give you an exact amount and all I can say is 'yes' - ie. the most basic positive word I know".

@MaciejStachowski what you just said in comment is, I think, the clearest and most compelling explanation I have seen.

Other responders have covered many aspects of the joke well.  Reinmar Bielau and cbh brought up the related-but-distinct pattern "Do you want X or Y?" "Yes."  (Which is about making choices, not stating degree.)  Joshua and cbh brought up the similar "All the things!" / "All the ways!"  Various people, including Dávid Laczkó and cbh, have touched on how this means the person would not be satisfied with any amount of coke, and from what I've seen, I think that's one of the core meanings of this joke format.
However, I don't think that the central logic of this joke format - "How much coke do you do?" "Y e s" - has been described in full by any of the answers, so I'll add my figurative two cents (which is to say, given where I'm posting, I'll respond as well and express my opinion, and the aspect that I think hasn't been fully touched on).
By responding to a question of degree ("How much...") in the affirmative ("YES."), the "Yes" is actually functioning as an expression of degree after all, despite not usually being a grammatically valid response to a question of degree in standard English.  "Yes" represents a degree, an answer to "How much...?", which is larger than all other, more specific, degrees.
It also conveys a significant degree of enthusiasm or emphasis, while still allowing the speaker to use a significantly understated tone: "How much coke do you want?" "Yes" has a large amount of emphasis while remaining completely deadpan.
So, in sum: they are asked how much coke they want, and they are stating that they want all of it.  They are implying they are enormously enthusiastic to get it (and so hyper-focused on its pursuit that they can't be bothered with minor details such as the rules of language - language won't stop them from getting their coke, which is all of the coke).  Perhaps they are even implying that the original question was mis-formed (because it implies that there was a point at which they might conceivably have enough coke - which is a premise they implicitly disagree with).  No matter what, they want the coke to keep on comin'.  They'll tell you when they've had enough, which is to say, they won't.
By flaunting the usual rules of English grammar (but still conveying a semantic meaning which responds to the original question), I see it as fairly excellent hyperbole.

This StackExchange thread should give more context as per this joke's origin: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504260/origin-of-yes-joke-to-a-question
The way the joke is generally interpreted, is that the respondent is embarrassed to reveal the true answer, so they simply respond "yes" as a cheeky way to confirm that they do the thing -- supposedly a lot.
For the "how much coke do you do", the "yes" can be interpreted as "I do more coke than I'm comfortable admitting".

I don't think being "embarrassed" about the true answer is part of the joke. It's hyperbole for humor, not for privacy.

@Todd Wilcox Agreed; from how I've seen it used, it's not about embarrassment, it's about degree, where "yes" is (cheekily!) used to represent a degree greater than any specific amount.  Joshua above (on Dávid Laczkó's answer) mentioned the similarity to "all the things!", which I think is a good comparison.

Otherwise:  Simon, nicely done finding that reference.   (Which Slate above added to the comments on OP's original question, either separately or pulled from your answer here - if the latter, I wish they'd credited you, but it could be ).  And while I haven't personally seen any hints of embarrassment (if anything, it's almost going the other direction by leaning into that hyperbole), I think you're representing the gist of the joke pretty well.  It still ends up as something like "How much coke do you do?" "I do more coke."

To me, as a native speaker, this appears to be another version of "No soap, radio!" . If so, the "joke" is that if you claim to get it you have demonstrated your susceptibility to social pressure, claiming to find it funny because you think you are expected to and aren't willing to say otherwise.
I would turn it back on them and accuse them of quoting nonsense because they aren't willing to admit they don't understand it. Make them explain their intent.
At best, this is bad writing. More likely it's a practical joke. At worst it could be someone looking for suckers who might fall for a scam. Social media attracts some decidedly antisocial individuals.

Not every joke you don't get is a social experiment. I have zero clue why "gyatt" and "rizzler" are hilarious to some, but while I like the idea of this all being just a huge prank Gen Z is playing on us millenials, it's more likely that I just don't get it.

@MaciejStachowski Interestingly, I do think that us millennials "not getting" those terms is part of what makes them popular.  It's not that they use the terms exclusively because they confuse older people.  But the idea that older people have no clue what they mean, or at least why they are "funny", probably does make it funnier for them to use.  As a kid I remember there being a pretty big appeal with words that adults didn't really understand.

I don't think it's a prank the Gen z is playing on the millennials; I think it's a prank they are playing on everybody including each other, and you just happen to be a millennial. I could certainly be wrong, but if so I suspect that rather than being wordplay this is a specific reference which is meaningless without knowing the context.

For this particular version of this joke, I would understand it as the answerer being so high on cocaine that he is unable to answer coherently. Which, itself, is kind of a back-handed answer to the question.
However, that wouldn't work in the general case.

Many have already mentioned the "all of it" ad it being an off-shoot of "X or Y", but I want to offer my interpretation.
With both "Do you want X or Y?" and "How much X do you want?", the "yes" is not a direct affirmation of "both" / "as much as possible" as it has been stated. Rather it is to be taken as "I don't care which/how much, but yes I want it". It's an answer stemming from lack of care, but still having a need.
E.g. in "Which haircut do you want?" the "yes" can be seen as "Yes I want a haircut, but I don't care what kind". Or going back to the coke, it can be the point of an addict "I don't care how much, just give me some / as much as you can" or from a inexperienced user "I don't know how much I want, but yes I want some".
Another take I've seen is that it is to be taken as a misunderstanding e.g. at a loud party. "How much have you had to drink?" "yes". The question was not or only partially understood and rather than possibly decline something the person answers with "yes".

This type of joke is classified "Non-Sequitur" which is "It does not follow" in Latin. It is a literary Device , usually occurring in comedy. [[ That Latin term also occurs in Logic , which we can ignore at the moment ]]
We can indeed see that the last line generally does not follow the question ( to match the situation )
In general , it is due to the last speaker being too dumb or too intelligent. There might be some convoluted way in which the response makes sense , though that might not be obvious at the initial glance.
Eg 1 :
When filling a form , a dumb guy sees "Name , Age , SEX" , where he enters "Yes" for "SEX" ( here "thrice a week" is a variation)
Initially , we see that the response does not follow the question. More thinking is required to make sense of the response.
Eg 2 :
When somebody asks a logician , whether he wants coffee ,  then he might say yes. It is indeed true that he wants coffee.
Naturally , when asked whether he wants coffee or tea , the answer is still yes ! It is still true that he wants either coffee or tea.
Logically , he wants to be asked which specific drink he wants , when he might then say coffee.
Eg 3 :
How many school kids like Pizza ??
We might expect something like 90% of the school kids.
Depending on whether the answerer is dumb or smart , it can be taken to mean "Wow , How many school kids like Pizza !!" , which is a rhetorical question. Hence the answer "YES" is either silly or accurate.
Eg 4 :
How funny are "Non-Sequitur" Jokes !!
Some might answer YES to that rhetorical question.
Some might answer that literal question with "Duh, I donno how funny those are. I just do not get it"
Over time , the internet meme trends have taken that over , where we can just put ABSOLUTELY/YES/NO to some complicated question which we do not want to answer appropriately at the moment.
Eg 5 :
How much Coke do you do ?
YES ( Interpretation is "YES , I agree that I do more Coke than normal" )
Eg 6 :
Do all such memes end with ABSOLUTELY/YES/NO ?
42 ( This is the Classic Non-Sequitur Joke )

In a conversation between two interlocutors, if one of them is telling a story or describing something that is hard to believe, the listener might say in American English:

What are you smoking? [implied: drug]
What drug are you on? [implied: it's making you hallucinate
Are you high or something? OR What are you high on?

So, "How much cocaine do you do?" [to have such an outrageous opinion] falls under this type of usage.
They are colloquial tropse that serve the purpose of saying: You must be kidding. What you say is not believable at all!
Example:
Some American politician - a woman known for saying outrageous things and telling lies - just recently said that the US government is controlling the weather (in the context of recent hurricanes). If someone were to repeat that to someone else, the reaction could very well be: What are you high on? due to the ridiculousness of the idea.
The "Yes" is not part of the trope. A B person could say any number of things here.
